# How to remove a member of a Gun unordered list

Tags: gun

Given the following gun unordered list, how is a machine remove from the list of machines?

```js
let gun = new Gun();
let machineId = 'cool-machine';
let location = {
  lat: position.coords.latitude,
  lng: position.coords.longitude
};

let machines = gun.get('machines');

let machine = gun.get('machine/' + machineId);
machine.put({machineId, location});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use gun/unset:

- include gun/unset either in node or browser. It is in the lib folder.

```js
machines.unset(machine);
```